# React router and nginx giving Unexpected Token <

Tags: reactjs, nginx, react-router

I have a react website which I am hosting inside a Docker container that is running Nginx, which I have running on Port 3000. I then have an instance of Nginx on my host machine, which I have a reverse proxy pointing to `127.0.0.1:3000`.

Everything works fine, except I have a Twitter authentication call, which uses a callback. When the url points back to `mysite.com/authenticated`, this is asking Nginx for the path which of course falls over.

I have scoured the internet and have found many posts indicating I should have this in my nginx default file:

```
location / {
        proxy_pass 127.0.0.1:3000;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }
```

When I then navigate to my website, even the root, I am getting `unexpected token <` in the console errors.

What could be causing this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Lets say you are calling external twitter api `http://twitter/auth.com/twitter/authentication` for authentication.
And in your react action file you have give url as `/twitter/authentication` to call.For this case following will be the configuration.

```
server { 

location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000;
    }
location /twitter/authentication  {
       proxy_pass http://twitter/auth.com;
       }
}
```

You have to write every location config inside server in nginx config.
After any modification in this config, you have restart nginx.

Answer (score 0):

For me it was the link to app.js

```
<script src="/app/bundle.js"></script>
```

When I tried to reach my App at

```
http://localhost:8080/serv9090
```

the browser tried to find /app/bundle.js via

```
http://localhost:8080/app/bundle.js
```

Which is not found at localhost:8080 (nginx)
For a first try I changed

```
<script src="/app/bundle.js"></script>
```

to

```
<script src="http://localhost:8080/serv9090/app/bundle.js"></script>
```

This worked fine.
Hope this helped.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by adding the following into the `nginx` `conf` file:

```
location ~ .(static)/(js|css|media)/(.+)$ {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /$1/$2/$3;
}
```